# C# How to get DataTable value

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datatable

I still new to C# and just have 3 months plus of learning process. I would like to seeking advice on how to extract data value from my DataTable I have create for validation checking.

```
private void checker 
{
    string sqlSelect2 = "SELECT a.AccNo, a.CompanyName , a.CreditLimit, FROM Debtor a JOIN";
}
```

which i have named  TableCehecker, i do not need to put it to gridview, just for checking purposes.

In the private void process how can I extract dataTable TableCehecker and the value?

Thank you,
Brian

Comment: Please post your actual code, not a stripped down version that could leave too much to interpretations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the Docs from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx):

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

You can then check whatever you want of data inside the DataTable either by querying or by looping through the rows and checking the column values.

Based on your comments, to extract values from single row:

```
DataRow drow = dt.Rows[0];
string value = drow.Field<string>("CompanyName");
```

Comment: Actually, i already extracted multiple tables into the a temporary data-table (tableCreditControl). Just i still down't how to get the data out. eventually the information inside that temporary data-table is only got 1 row of data.

I try top get the data information inside the private void X1 (for example)

Comment: @BrianNg checked the updated answer on how to get value from the first record.

Comment: I think where i have gone wrong, because the temporary datatable is still the SQL table, i need to look for SQL command to get the value out.
Anyway Thank you for the help user318559. I will try out your advice as well.

Comment: @BrianNg you can select the data from the temp table in the same query that create the temp table, and continue the logic as above. Like `SELECT whatever from #tempTableName`